# Google plus api sign in (iOS) only works when logged into chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, html, google-chrome, google-plus

This only applies to iOS. pc/mac browsers seem to be fine.

So the google plus api works just fantastic... as long as the user is logged in to chrome. If a user goes to my site using Safari on their iphone or on chrome but not logged in, the sign-in button doesn't do anything. Doesn't click, nothing.

Here's the html, taken basically straight from the api site.

```
<span id="signinButton" class="span12">
<span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="onSigninCallback"
    data-clientid="771400051000-sh72h9d1tu6h14cuvtmt0ohm8ovd7o09.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email">
</span>
```

And here's the javascript. I'm not including the helper functions because I don't think they're the problem. I think if they were just getting called then they'd work, I figure the problem must be with the onSignInCallback getting an authResult when not logged in to chrome. If you want any more detail, just ask :)

```
onSignInCallback: function(authResult) {
  gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
    $('#authResult').html('Auth Result:<br/>');
    for (var field in authResult) {
      $('#authResult').append(' ' + field + ': ' +
          authResult[field] + '<br/>');
    }
    if (authResult['access_token']) {
      $('#authOps').show();
      $('#gConnect').hide();
      var email_promise = helper.email();
      email_promise.done(function(email_result) {
            helper.profile(email_result);
        });


    } else if (authResult['error']) {
      // There was an error, which means the user is not signed in.
      // As an example, you can handle by writing to the console:
      console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
      $('#authResult').append('Logged out');
      $('#authOps').hide('slow');
      $('#gConnect').show();
    }
    console.log('authResult', authResult);
  });
}
```